# remove cross image button in facebook sample

Tags: android

I downloaded facebook sample code from the following link: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk. And i am trying to run that sample code and I got login screen in that login screen left corner cross image button is available. and when ever I click that button login screen is closed.and my question is how to remove cross image button

Comment: you could just remove the imageview for the close image. it would be in the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this SDK There is file named **`FbDialog.java`**

in that file there is Method named **`CreateCrossImage()`**

in this file it self there is line new 90 to 95 line number

```
mContent.addView(mCrossImage, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

just comment this line and done forget to give permissions...
and un-comment the lastly commented lines....

this are the Permissions...

```
private String[] permissions = { "user_about_me",
    "user_activities", "user_birthday", "user_hometown", "user_likes",
    "user_photos", "user_status", "user_events", "user_groups",
    "user_location", "user_website", "offline_access", "read_mailbox",
    "read_stream", "email", "publish_stream", "user_location",
    "publish_checkins", "user_work_history", "friends_likes",
    "friends_hometown", "friends_birthday", "friends_hometown",
    "friends_location", "friends_photos", "friends_website" };
```

`mFacebook = new Facebook("FaceBookApplicationId");`

```
    mFacebook.authorize(Sample.this, permissions,
            new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "Facebook Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Toast.makeText(Sample.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Toast.makeText(Sample.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(Sample.this, "Connection Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried. But I am getting force close screen.And I got the error in oncreate method in my activity class

Comment: I tried and got the blank screen.And in logcat the following error is displayed: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

Comment: here it is working completely fine...
have you given the Internet permission..????

Comment: but if you want that not no close this dialog so u have to override backButton also...@user1717339